# Date partition or date sharded

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have many tables in BigQuery that are date sharded, including several years of Google Analytics data. I was recently told that this was the old method of optimization and that date partitioning is much faster.

Is this correct? I am always looking for ways to improve query speed over this data, if date partitioning allows for much faster querying should I rebuild all my date sharded GA tables as date partitioned instead? Should I do both? What kind of performance impact could I expect to see and is it really worth the effort?

Comment: Read this one for some best practices: https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b

Answer (score 1):

This page in Google's documentation answers this relatively thoroughly: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#partitioning_versus_sharding

Most relavent section:

> Partitioned tables perform better than tables sharded by date. When you create date-named tables, BigQuery must maintain a copy of the schema and metadata for each date-named table. Also, when date-named tables are used, BigQuery might be required to verify permissions for each queried table. This practice also adds to query overhead and impacts query performance. The recommended best practice is to use partitioned tables instead of date-sharded tables

Your performance improvements will depend most upon how many previous shards you have and how many of them you consistently access in single queries.

Comment: Good one Eric, I would like to add that one of the major releases of BigQuery is clustering which is an index which enables quick access and reduces cost. This feature is only available on new partition tables. See this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables) for more details.

Comment: Thanks both,  I read the docs but was looking for some real world reinforcement before I rebuild a lot of tables - I guess I better get to work partitioning!

Comment: Ah, hopefully someone stops in who has done the process themselves. Otherwise please update with some runtime examples if you go ahead with it.

Comment: I was considering partitioning by date as well, but it seems like a combo of sharding and partitioning is necessary because there's tables have a limit of 4000 partitions